# VT-x is disabled in BIOS. No USB devices or running emulators detected error

Tags: android, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run a basic android hello world app on a virtual device and I get these errors when i try to select a virtual Device. I went in my bios already and my intel virtual tech is enable so I'm at a lost now what could cause this error.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might occur due to various reasons. I had the same problem with my PC. I had a AMD CPU ,turns-out AMD won't support Intel HAX-M and i had to find alternate way to use emulator. So, i started using GenyMotion emulator

I recommend using GenyMotion emulator, its free and supports all platforms.

Comment: It worked on my pc before, but than suddenly i get this error. ;c